# Sound sensor dont work in whole project

Tags: arduino-uno, led, home-automation

When I put this code only on arduino, sound sensor works:

```
int soundSensor=A1;
int LED=5;


boolean LEDStatus=false;


void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600);

  pinMode(soundSensor,INPUT);
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {


  int SensorData=analogRead(soundSensor); 


  if(SensorData>600){

    if(LEDStatus==false){
        LEDStatus=true;
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    }
    else{
        LEDStatus=false;
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    }

    delay(50);
  }



 }
```

When I upload same code in big project, even when I upload little part of project on arduino, sound sensor doesnt work.. whats happening?

I checked soundsensor with everything. 
I leave whole code till void loop ()  and sound sensor works.
But if I put even delay(1000) in void loop after, sound sensor doesnt work.

Also, if I put every other thing : servo, dht, lighting in code with sound sensor.. with or without delay... sound sensor doesnt work!

Thanks

Whole code:

```
#include <Servo.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define SERVO_PIN 8
#define SS_PIN 10
#define RST_PIN 9
#define lightingOutput A2
#define ldrPin A0
#define PIR 7
#define ledGrn 6
#define heatingOutput A3
#define coolingOutput A4
#define DHTPIN 2
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN); // Create instance of our reader
Servo myservo; // Create instance of our motor /// create servo object to control a servo
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);     //// Initialize DHT sensor for normal 16mhz Arduino

int pos;
int light;
float h, t;
int soundSensor=A1;
int LED=5;
boolean LEDStatus=false;
const int buzzer = 4;
long zadnje_ocitanje=0;  

void setup()
{

  Serial.begin(9600);
  dht.begin();
  SPI.begin();
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();
  myservo.attach(SERVO_PIN);
  myservo.write(0);

  pinMode(heatingOutput, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(coolingOutput, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ledGrn, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(soundSensor,INPUT);
  pinMode(LED,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(lightingOutput, OUTPUT);

  zadnje_ocitanje=millis();
}
void loop() {

  Serial.println("\nHOME AUTOMATION\n");

  readSOUND();
  readRFID();
  readDHT();
  readLIGHT();

delay(1000);

}

////////////////////////////////////////////
void readRFID()

{
  //Look for new cards
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent() ) {
    return;
  }
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial() ) {
    return;
  }
  // If a card is detected, execute the following:
  Serial.println("Time to open");
  // Print the card's ID
  String content = "";
  byte letter;
  for ( byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++ ) {
    content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
    if ( i < mfrc522.uid.size - 1 ) content += "-";
  }
  content.toUpperCase();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("UID tag :'" + content + "'");

  if (content == "C0-E5-86-25") {

    Serial.println("Authorized access");
     digitalWrite(ledGrn, HIGH);

    for (pos = 0; pos <= 90; pos += 1) {
      myservo.write(pos);
      delay(25);
    }
    for (pos = 90; pos >= 0; pos -= 1) {
      myservo.write(pos);
      delay(70);
      digitalWrite(ledGrn, LOW);
    }
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Access Denied");
      tone(buzzer, 1000, 6000);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void readDHT()
{

  h = dht.readHumidity();
  t = dht.readTemperature();
  Serial.print("Humidity: ");
  Serial.print(h);
  Serial.print(" %\t");
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(t);
  Serial.print(" *C ");
  Serial.println();

  if (t < 18) //if temperature is less than 18 celcius
  {
    digitalWrite(heatingOutput, HIGH);
    Serial.print("Heating activated\n");
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(heatingOutput, LOW);
  }

  if (t > 22) //if temperature is more than 22 celcius
  {
    digitalWrite(coolingOutput, HIGH);
    Serial.print("Cooling activated\n");
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(coolingOutput, LOW);
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void readLIGHT()
{

 int value_pir = digitalRead(PIR);
 light = map(analogRead(ldrPin) , 0 , 1024 , 1 , 100);

  Serial.print("Lighting percentage: ");
  Serial.print(light);
  Serial.print("\nMotion detector: ");
  Serial.print(digitalRead(PIR));


if ((millis()-zadnje_ocitanje)>6000)   
  {    

  if ((light < 50) && ( value_pir == HIGH) )                            
  {
    digitalWrite(lightingOutput, HIGH);
    Serial.println("\nLighting ON");
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(lightingOutput, LOW);
    Serial.println("\nLighting OFF");
  }
    zadnje_ocitanje=millis(); 
  }
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

void readSOUND()
{
  int SensorData=analogRead(soundSensor); 

  if(SensorData>600){

    if(LEDStatus==false){
        LEDStatus=true;
        digitalWrite(LED,HIGH);
    }
    else{
        LEDStatus=false;
        digitalWrite(LED,LOW);
    }

    delay(50);
  }

}
```

Comment: See his post on Arduino.cc for additional information before you go too far.  https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=626641.0

Comment: You found on that thread that your sound sensor does indeed work.  It's just that you have your threshold set wrong?  Put a line there to print the reading from the sensor.  Does it every go over 600?  We just found out on Arduino.cc that it doesn't.